# Where not to use core data? Is it possible to use core data as a database like MySql?

Tags: ios, core-data, sqlite

Core data is simple, efficient, and mind blowing if we know where to use and **where not to**.

I have been playing with Core data for a while.

I want to know **Where not to use core data**.

The question is simple, lets say, I want to use core data as a real "Database" like MySql.

Have primary key, search, sort (with one or more columns) etc..

As far as I tried I couldn't achieve it.

There is no useful documentation or help anywhere I can find for "havingPredicate".

Is choosing to use core data in the place of a DB is a potential liability? 
or
If it is possible, is there a particular "core data model" in which it can be done or at least most of it can be done.. (with limitations which is distinct)?

Comment: Core Data is a beautiful creation of highly optimised tools neatly packaged into an Objective-C framework to help us manage a persistent store (one example of a persistent store is a database). It is itself NOT a database. It is often formally referred to as an object graph. Use of Core Data depends on a number of factors, such as what type of data do you want to store and how often do you need to access it?

Answer (score 1):

Core Data provides some database-like features, but with an API that's different from using raw SQL statements. For example, Core Data entities are *roughly* equivalent to SQL tables, but its handling of relationships is very different from how SQL works. Whether it's a "potential liability" depends on what you need to accomplish in your app. Core Data was designed as a system that allows reading and writing of model objects directly, and while it has some features similar to SQL, thinking in terms of SQL is a good way to screw it up.

> Have primary key, search, sort (with one or more columns) etc..
>
> As far as I tried I couldn't achieve it.

Core Data uses its own unique ID system which serves as a primary key. Every instance of `NSManagedObject` has a property called `objectID` which is unique. You can add your own primary key fields but it's up to you to ensure uniqueness. It's typically not necessary, but again it really depends on what you need to accomplish. Searching and sorting are built in via `NSPredicate` and `NSSortDescriptor`. If you found this to be difficult or impossible, it would be a good idea to post a new question with details of what you tried and how it failed to do what you needed.

> There is no useful documentation or help anywhere I can find for "havingPredicate".

It serves the same purpose as in SQL via `NSPredicate`. The syntax is different, so you might want to consult Apple's [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html) to see how it works. As a simple example, the SQL fragment `HAVING SUM(SaleAmount) > 1000` would be realized with something like `@sum(saleAmount) > 1000)`.